# how to add target blank to an href.location hyperlink

Tags: javascript, target

I'm trying to get a link in javascript to open a url in a new tab. I've found a number of posts for target="blank" using attribute and a couple other ways but can't seem to get it to work. Basically, if v_virt = "invoices" I just need the url to open in a new tab. Does anyone know the proper syntax?

```js
if(v_virt=="invoices"){
location.href=('https://www.example.com/invoices/invoice?ProjectID=[@field:ProjectID]&InvoiceID=[@field:InvoiceID]', '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `window.open()` rather than `location.href`.

- `location.href` changes the URL of the current page;
- `window.open()` opens a new pop-up window navigated to the specified page.

For example:

```
window.open('https://www.example.com/invoices/invoice?ProjectID=[@field:ProjectID]&InvoiceID=[@field:InvoiceID]');
```

Comment: Is there any way to not use a popup? A lot of my users have popup blockers and will get confused if they have to ok it.

Comment: Also, thanks for clarifying the difference between location.href and window.open. I wasn't quite clear on that.

Comment: I see the link above with a similar issue re tabs vs popup. The odd thing is I have my test browser (chrome) set up to open new windows in tabs but this code forces a popup.

Comment: @KevinL Opening a new tab / window technically is a popup, which is sad in a way as sometimes there are legitimate use cases for it. You could always do something like this if it is a large problem for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mbqvjhpw/

Comment: thanks for the link & explanation- really helps